# Deploying multiple validating webhooks in the same kubernates cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I am working with an AKS cluster and AKS comes with an pre-deployed instance of Gatekeeper for validating webhooks.

However by design, AKS would only allow predefined or custom policies to be deployed through Azure policy portal. This is against the developer experience that I am trying to build, where developers would be free to deploy their own gatekeeper policies using kubectl.

Hence this got me thinking if I can deploy a separate instance of gatekeeper on the same cluster and create a new validating webhook configuration ? Would that even work ?

If yes, what all changes would need to be made.. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a another gatekeeper instance. You can apply your policies to the pre-deployed instance of Gatekeeper. For this you have 2 options:

1. [OPA ConstraintTemplates](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/howto/)
2. [Azure Custom policy definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-policy#create-and-assign-a-custom-policy-definition-preview)